# форматированный вывод c#

Tags: c#

```
 Console.WriteLine("{0:f4}",c);
```

Как в данную строку вместо  `f4`  - на место 4 подставить переменную в которую будет попадать нужное количество знаков

Comment: первый параметр обычная строка, соответственно и собрать ее можно  как угодно используя какие угодно переменные

Answer (score 3):

Первый параметр – обычная строка, соответственно и собрать ее можно как угодно используя какие угодно переменные, начиная с обычной конкатенации

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:f"+i+"}",c);
```

Заканчивая [интерполированием строк](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/dn961160.aspx), которое позволяет уйти от прямого вызова `string.Format`

```
Console.WriteLine($"{{0:f{i}}}",c);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{{0:f{0}}}", i),c);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ описание кода, чтобы пользователям было легче его понять. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/147577)